# ¿Como apuntar phpmyadmin local al servidor windows 2012?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Instalé xampp en un servidor windows server 2012 y estoy en proceso de configuracion, lo que quiero es conectarme al servidor desde mi maquina local, hice la prueba de ping y llego al servidor, en mi pc local configure el archivo config.inc.php, estaba asi originalmente:

```
|$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
 $cfg['Lang'] = '';

 /* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1'; 
  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';|
```

Y la linea que dice `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';`
lo cambio por la ip de mi servidor pero me niega el acceso me da el siguiente error:

Error
MySQL ha dicho:

```
Documentación

#1130 - Host 'android-2afb7d8b283f83f7.domarzobispado.cl' is not allowed to connect to 
this MariaDB server

mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host 'android-2afb7d8b283f83f7' is not allowed to 
connect to this MariaDB server

La conexión para controluser, como está definida en su configuración, fracasó.

mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1130): Host 'android-2afb7d8b283f83f7' is not allowed to 
connect to this MariaDB server

phpMyAdmin intentó conectarse con el servidor MySQL, y el servidor rechazó esta conexión. 
Deberá revisar el host, nombre de usuario y contraseña en config.inc.php y asegurarse que 
corresponden con la información provista por el administrador del servidor MySQL.
```

Comment: Estimado esta bien asi?

Comment: Si, mucho mejor. Piensa que las imagenes pueden romperse los links y quedar sin sentido la pregunta, además de que los usuarios desde movil tarda más y gastan más datos hehe